# How do you add the results of a C# for-loop?

Tags: c#, object, methods, for-loop

I have the program setup to ask for the amount of minutes and cost per minute then it calculates cost for that phone call. I have a for loop setup to go through this 3 times. My question is how do I display the combined cost of all 3 calls?

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;


namespace phonecall
{
    class Call
    {
        public
        int callid;  //used with counter in the main()
        int minutes;     //minutes
        double costpermin;  //output for per minute cost
        double pricepercall;    //output for total cost


        public void getdata(int x) //this method gets the data and stores it in the class data members
        {
            callid = ++x;

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the number minutes: ");
            minutes = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the price per minute: ");
            costpermin = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            pricepercall = minutes * costpermin;
        }

        public void displaydata() //this method displays the values of the class data members
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Call Number: {0}", callid);
            Console.WriteLine("Number of Minutes: {0}", minutes);
            Console.WriteLine("Cost Per Minute: ${0}", costpermin);
            Console.WriteLine("Total cost of Call: ${0}", pricepercall);
            Console.WriteLine();

        }
    }


    class forloop
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Call myCall = new Call(); //instantiation of the Call class

            for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) //will get the data for 3 calls
            {

                myCall.getdata(x); //calls the object method and takes the value of x to use when getting data from the user
                myCall.displaydata(); //calls the object method to display the data
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have your `getData()` method return the cost of the call:

```
public double getdata(int x) //this method gets the data and stores it in the class data members
{
  callid = ++x ;
  Console.WriteLine("Enter the number minutes: ");
  minutes = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
  Console.WriteLine("Enter the price per minute: ");
  costpermin = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
  pricepercall = minutes * costpermin;
  return pricePercall; 
}
```

Now you can just sum them up:

```
double sumPrices = 0;
for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) //will get the data for 3 calls
{
   sumPrices+=myCall.getdata(x); //calls the object method and takes the value of x to use when getting data from the user
   myCall.displaydata(); //calls the object method to display the data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    double costforallcalls;

    for(int i = 0; i < 3;i++)
    {
        costforallcalls += minutes * costpercall


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a variable that tracks you costs in the for loop and then write it out

```
double runningTotal = 0;
for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) //will get the data for 3 calls
{
    myCall.getdata(x); //calls the object method and takes the value of x to use when getting data from the user
    runningTotal += myCall.pricepercall;
    myCall.displaydata(); //calls the object method to display the data
    Console.WriteLine("Running Total: {0}", runningTotal);
}
```

Or alternatively you could create an object for each call and keep the around and then total them when ever you needed the running total

```
var callList = new List<Call>();
for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) //will get the data for 3 calls
{
    var myCall = new Call();
    myCall.getdata(x); //calls the object method and takes the value of x to use when getting data from the user
    myCall.displaydata(); //calls the object method to display the data
    callList.Add(myCall);
}


Console.WriteLine("Running Total: ${0}", callList.Sum (c => c.pricepercall));
```

Obviously pricepercall would need to be a public property to do this.

Hope this helps.